# Fix beds24 booking button on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I'm implementing beds24 booking hotel booking management on wordpress website. It uses the iframe for making booking, its working fine on pc, but when I'm trying on mobile device the button is not clickable.

```
<div class="btn button at_bookingbut propfrombutton"><a href="?ownerid=xxxxx&amp;propid=xxxxx">Book Now</a></div>
```

Some property of class btn is causing issue, by adding `.btn{height:0!important}` in beds24 css field, the button is clickable but it's functioning only on clicking the text part not full button area.